# List form connected with library (list form with document file)

Tags: 2010, document-library, infopath, list-form

I have a list and a form to it. What I need:

- form with specific word file in it which can be edited (so user open form and he can see fields to fill and one field with document that he have to edit)
- this word file should be saved in library after the form is completed (every list item should create separate word file in library)

Is it possible to do it in InfoPath 2013? If yes, how can I do it?

Comment: I do not recommend you to use InfoPath at all, you tie yourself to the MS Office product and move away to the ability to work through mobile devices, as well as large timeouts when loading DataSource.

Comment: I agree, that using InfoPath is not a good idea. What about a document template within Document Library and custom Fields for such a document? This way you would fulfill your requirements using OOB features of SharePoint (but unfortunately/fortunately without an InfoPath)